# How to open one namespace from another within the same project?

Tags: f#

I'm trying to learn a bit of F#, coming from C#. I've got a new library project with two code files in it. Each code file is in a different namespace. I need to open one of the namespaces from the other file though. I don't seem to be able to actually open that other namespace, though. It's like it doesn't exist. Can anybody point out what I'm doing wrong?

Here's a screen shot of my project structure, for reference ...

[image]

LeagueTeam.fs:

```
namespace League.Entity2.Database

type LeagueTeam() =
    member val Id = 0L with get, set
    member val Name = "" with get, set
    member val DateCreated = System.DateTime.Now with get, set
```

TeamGetByIdResponse.js

```
namespace League.Entity2.WebApi

open League.Entity2.Database

type TeamGetByIdResponse() =
    member val Team = new LeagueTeam() with get, set
```

In the `TeamGetByIdResponse.fs` file, I need to set a property using the type from the `LeagueTeam.fs` file. So, when I try to `open` that namespace to use the type I get intellisense for `League.Entity2` namespace, but I don't see the `Database` namespace used in the `LeagueTeam.fs` file. If I manually type in `open League.Entity2.Database` it says that the module `League` cannot be found.

Do namespaces work a bit differently in F# than C#?

Comment: What is the order of the files in the project?

Comment: Like, in the project file itself? Or in the solution explorer? Does my screenshot show what you're asking? The `TeamgetByIdResponse` file comes first in the project file itself.

Comment: F# requires you to order your project files by dependency order: if B.fs needs code from A.fs, then A.fs must come first in the .fsproj file and B.fs must come second. This is a deliberate design decision intended to make [circular dependencies](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/cyclic-dependencies/) difficult to write. (You're allowed to have circular dependencies within one file, but not between two files). Edit the .fsproj file and move `TeamGetByIdResponse.fs` to be below the `LeagueTeam.fs` file it depends on, and you should be able to open the namespace and use it.

Comment: In Visual Studio, you can also move files up and down with Alt+Up and Alt-Down.